# Background color not being set in Footer

Tags: css, html

I have changed the footer's background color to yellow but the code just is not working. 
I have been working on this for past 2 hours. Please don't bash me out!
Just help. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
            #footerMain{
                min-width: 1000px;
                background-color: yellow;
            }

            .footerLeft{
                position: absolute;
                height: 20px;
                width: 80px;

            }

            .footerRight{
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: 800px; 
                height: 20px;
                width: 80px;

            }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <footer id="footerMain">
        <div class="footerLeft">
            <h1>Hello</h1>  
        </div>
        <div class="footerRight">
            <h1>Bye</h1>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this , HTML

```
<footer id="footerMain" class="clearfix">
        <div class="footerLeft">
            <h1>Hello</h1>  
        </div>
        <div class="footerRight">
            <h1>Bye</h1>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS:

```
.clearix{
    zoom:1;
}

.clearfix:after, .clearfix:before{
    line-height: 0;
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after{
    clear:both;
}



#footerMain{
    background-color:yellow;
}

div.footerLeft{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

div.footerRight{
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thank You. 
Can you take a look at this code and tell me what's wrong with it? Because I am not able to change the background color of footer. :/
https://jsfiddle.net/Lkgbanct/

Comment: @GautamHans , let me take a look :)

Comment: @GautamHans just add the clearfix css which I showed you , and then add it as a class to the footer, <footer id="footerMain" class="clearfix">

Comment: @GautamHans If i helped you , mark my answer as checked , thanks :)

Comment: Thank You Very Much Man !!!
One more question, if you don't mind.
I can't make the contents of two divs to extreme left or extreme right now.
Like I want contents of footerLeft in extreme left and footerRight in extreme right.
Any way to do that?

Comment: Did you try to float them? , like float:left and float:right? btw. copy my clearfix css , and when u use float property , add clearfix class to its parent !

Comment: @GautamHans bro , remove the margins for your divs inside the footer , like u have margin-left:5 % for your left item , and margin-right:5% for your right , item , remove them  , and they'll be extreme in the left and right side!

Comment: bro, Sadly, that is not working. I added clearfix to the before the divs and then removed the margin. But both steps didn't do anything.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you man. But it is working now.
I think there was some kind of hidden stray because of unregistered version of Sublime Text. Edited in N++ and followed all your steps again. Working fine now. :) Thank you very much for helping brother.

Comment: @GautamHans np brother , you can always ask me for something! If you need something else , send me a message etc. I enjoy helping people!

Comment: Will do. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using position absolute; so basically `#footerMain` has no height, but still, you better not use position absoute, more robust way would be floating property

```css
#footerMain{
                min-width: 1000px;
                background: yellow;
                height: 100px; /* add height & add more height, because h1 has margin */
            }

            .footerLeft{
                float: left; /*remove position: absolute;*/
                height: 20px;
                width: 80px;

            }

            .footerRight{
                float: right; /*remove position: absolute;*/
                height: 20px;
                width: 80px;
            }
```

```html
<footer id="footerMain">
        <div class="footerLeft">
            <h1>Hello</h1>  
        </div>
        <div class="footerRight">
            <h1>Bye</h1>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Thank You !! It worked.
BTW, I was facing the real problem in this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lkgbanct/

Mind taking a look there and posting for solution to that also. 
Thanks. :)

Comment: Just add `height: 50px; ` to _#footerMain_

Answer (score 1):

Your `#footerMain` element contains only `absolute`-positioned elements. Therefore, it is considered empty as far as layout goes. Consequently, its height is zero, making it invisible.

Add some height to it - probably `20px` to match the height of the elements.

Comment: Thank You. Can you take a look at this code and tell me what's wrong with it? Because I am not able to change the background color of footer. :/ jsfiddle.net/Lkgbanct

Comment: Floating elements have the same problem. Use `overflow:hidden` or a clearing element to fix. http://jsfiddle.net/Lkgbanct/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add a height rule to `footerMain` like 40px